# -11855 error code when using AVFoundation with high res video. What resolution should I use?

Tags: ios, ipad, react-native, avfoundation

[image]

Using react-native-video to play a simple video it fails at resolutions greater than 1024x768 on older devices (ipad 2, ipad 3rd gen (A1416)) with the error below.

```
{
    "target": 4,
    "error": {
       "code": -11855,
       "domain": "AVFoundationErrorDomain"
    }
}
```

I can't find this error in the list of [AVFoundation error constants](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/av_foundation_error_constants/error_codes). It stops at -11852.

I have found through testing that the maximum resolution I can use on 2nd or 3rd gen ipads is 1024x768, but I can't find this documented anywhere. An ipad mini 2 can play video at 2048x2048 without trouble.

What resolution can I use that will work with all iPads?
Can I display different media like 1x and 2x images on iPads that have different capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iPad 2 has the following specifications:**

---

**Video formats supported:**

- H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1
  with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, 
  and .mov file formats;
- MPEG‑4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
  Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz,
  stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
- Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels,    30 frames
  per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in    .avi file format

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp622?locale=en_GB

---

---

**iPad 3 has the following specifications:**

---

**Video formats supported:**

- H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1
  with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4,
  and .mov file formats;
- MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
  Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz,
  stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
- Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per
  second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp647?locale=en_GB

---

---

As you can see, it doesn't support resolution greater than 1080p i.e. 1920 by 1080 so 2048 by 2048 won't work.

-18555 error description is in file AVError.h (https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/averror/averrorundecodablemediadata)

```
AVErrorUndecodableMediaData NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0)  = -11855,
```

Though there is not enough description given to give a concrete conclusion but from the name we can say that it means it cannot decode the video as it's beyond device capability.

Comment: All good comments, only 1024x768 seems to be the limit for h264 mp4 video in my tests, whether using react native or AVFoundation natively.

Comment: Please check the encoding and profile (main vs baseline vs high) of the file you are trying to play.

Comment: Managed to sort this out, problem was when I tested it I accidentally used a square of 1920x1920 instead of 1920x1080. At 1920x1080 it works fine.